# what do i need to do so that mod_wsgi will find libmysqlclient.16.dylib? (osx 10.7 with apache mod_wsgi)

Tags: django, macos, apache, osx-lion, mod-wsgi

I am trying to run django on osx 10.7 (lion) with apache mod_wsgi and virtualenv. 
My site works if I use the django testing server:

> ```
> (baseline)otter:hello mathew$ python manage.py runserver
> ```

but it doesn't work when I run apache. The core of the error seems to be

> ```
> Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib
> ```

I think its to do with the path apache is using to locate libmysqlclient.16.dylib

when I run otool in the lib directory it looks good

> ```
> otter:lib mathew$ pwd
>     /usr/local/mysql/lib
>
> otter:lib mathew$ otool -L libmysqlclient.16.dylib
>     libmysqlclient.16.dylib:
>       libmysqlclient.16.dylib (compatibility version 16.0.0, current version 16.0.0)
>       /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.0.1)
> ```

but from outside it can't find it

> ```
> otter:lib mathew$ cd /
> otter:/ mathew$ otool -L libmysqlclient.16.dylib
> otool: can't open file: libmysqlclient.16.dylib (No such file or directory)
> ```

if i manually set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH otool works

> otter:lib mathew$ DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib otter:lib
>   mathew$ otool -L libmysqlclient.16.dylib libmysqlclient.16.dylib:
>     libmysqlclient.16.dylib (compatibility version 16.0.0, current
>   version 16.0.0)   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version
>   1.0.0, current version 125.0.1)

When I run the django testing server, my .bash_profile sets up the virtualenv and the path to the mysql dynamic library

> ```
> export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
> export PATH
> ```

When i run apache it finds my virtualenv paths, but it doesn't seem to find the dynamic library path.

I tried adding this path to /usr/sbin/envvars

> ```
> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib:/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
> export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
> ```

and to /private/etc/paths.d/libmysql

> ```
> /usr/local/mysql/lib
> ```

then restarted the machine
but that has not changed the error message.

> ```
> Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/usr/local/python_virtualenv/baseline/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so,
> ```
>
> 2): 
>           Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib

I don't think is a permissions issue:

> ```
> -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  3787328  4 Dec  2010 libmysqlclient.16.dylib
>
> drwxr-xr-x  39 root    wheel   1394 18 Nov 21:07 /
> drwxr-xr-x@ 15 root    wheel    510 24 Oct 22:10 /usr
> drwxrwxr-x  20 root    admin    680  2 Nov 20:22 /usr/local
> drwxr-xr-x  20 mathew  admin    680  9 Nov 21:58 /usr/local/python_virtualenv
> drwxr-xr-x   6 mathew  admin    204  2 Nov 21:36 /usr/local/python_virtualenv/baseline
> drwxr-xr-x   4 mathew  admin    136  2 Nov 21:26 /usr/local/python_virtualenv/baseline/lib
> drwxr-xr-x  52 mathew  admin   1768  2 Nov 21:26 /usr/local/python_virtualenv/baseline/lib/python2.7
> drwxr-xr-x  18 mathew  admin    612  4 Nov 21:20 /usr/local/python_virtualenv/baseline/lib/python2.7/site-packages
> -rwxr-xr-x   1 mathew  admin  66076  2 Nov 21:18 /usr/local/python_virtualenv/baseline/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
> ```

**What do i need to do so that mod_wsgi will find libmysqlclient.16.dylib?**

apache and mysql are both 64 bit:

> otter:lib mathew$ file /usr/sbin/httpd /usr/sbin/httpd: Mach-O
>   universal binary with 2 architectures /usr/sbin/httpd (for
>   architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64 /usr/sbin/httpd
>   (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386 otter:lib mathew$
>
> otter:lib mathew$ file /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib 
>   /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit
>   dynamically linked shared library x86_64

---

update: it's not a real solution, but I have got around the error using:

> ```
> sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/python_virtualenv/baseline/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
> ```

You can find an explanation at: http://qin.laya.com/tech_coding_help/dylib_linking.html and on the google groups mod_wsgi mailing list page: http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_thread/thread/6517dc90be9d43ff

Answer (score 1):

Question also asked on mod_wsgi mailing list at:

http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_thread/thread/6517dc90be9d43ff

I will be answering it on the mailing list when I get the opportunity to sit down and focus on it.